# Take this opportunity vs take up this opportunity

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have just watched a british youtube video. She said:

"I really hope some of you **take up this opportunity"**

My question is, what is the *difference* of that to
**"Take this opportunity"**

Is this regional?

Comment: Please provide a link to the video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To **take an opportunity** is to simply take advantage of a situation that has made it possible to do something. The rain stopped, so I took the opportunity to go out; my train was late so I took the opportunity to drink a cup of coffee. I took the opportunity to speak to John while I was in London.

To **take up an opportunity, offer, chance, etc** is to accept an offer, or take advantage of an opportunity, that someone has made available. Schools are taking up the offer of cut-price computers; young people are taking up the opportunity of a career offered by Central Bank Ltd. I took up John's offer of a meeting while I was in London.